# Explanation of window.performance javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on detecting the connection speed, so i planned to go with [window.performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975075) object for duration calculation.

I am little confused with window.performance.timing object is generated based on the whole page load, or based on the last request and response.

For Example:

I am having 5 server call for web page load, `performance.timing` object is generated based on all the 5 server calls or based on the 5th server call(last call).

**sample connection speed calculation for reference**

```
 var bitsLoaded = 100000; //bits total size of all files (5 server call).
 var duration = performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;
 var speedBps = Math.round(bitsLoaded / duration);
 var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
 var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
```

Anything not clear ready to explain

Any idea about window.performance

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[image: performance.timing]

Not sure if this chart gives you a better understanding of performance.timing.

**For your question:**

> I am having 5 server call for web page load, performance.timing object
>   is generated based on all the 5 server calls or based on the 5th
>   server call(last call).

The answer is: `performance.timing` is generated based on **all requests and responses** (but not including the ajax ones).

**For the sample connection speed calculation script you gave**, I guess the below one is better.

```
var duration = performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.responseStart;
```

The reason is: the duration from `navigationStart` to `responseEnd` **includes DNS timing which does not transfer any data from server to client**.

Please refer to https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html for the definition of timings.

Comment: Note that `performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.responseStart;` will only measure the time that the root document (eg, HTML) took to be sent from the server, not the 5 server calls and 100000 bits that karthick mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

performance.timing is NOT based on the last request and response. It measures the delay between **navigationStart** stage and **loadEventStart** stage in a page life cycle. As explained [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/), it's main use is to determine the Page Load Speed.
In my opinion. performance.timing can't really be used for measuring connection speed since it's initiated **After** the user has received the response and is a javascript object, which runs on the browser. I suggest you simply ping the user and use the round trip time.

Comment: Hi, I am still bit confused on how it really works but I do get the general facts. For opening I used "navigationStart and loadEventStart", which would be correct right?. Now I have a question as this performance class happens when the page is being loaded or the url is being accessed (Based on my understanding?).. then how can I get the speed of closing a web page? Is it another class?