# Understanding the meaning of parameters in the performance timing object obtained from Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to retrieve performance metrics from a webpage. I have the following code snippet:

```js
await page.goto(url);
const perfEntries = JSON.parse(await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(performance.toJSON())));
console.log(perfEntries);
```

The output of perfEntries is a JSON object that includes a timing property with various parameters and their corresponding values. Here is an example of the output:

```json
{
    "timeOrigin": 1684471690080.1,
    "timing": {
        "connectStart": 1684471690986,
        "navigationStart": 1684471690080,
        "secureConnectionStart": 1684471690986,
        "fetchStart": 1684471690633,
        "domContentLoadedEventStart": 1684471692121,
        "responseStart": 1684471691209,
        "domInteractive": 1684471691395,
        "domainLookupEnd": 1684471690986,
        "responseEnd": 1684471691344,
        "redirectStart": 0,
        "requestStart": 1684471690986,
        "unloadEventEnd": 0,
        "unloadEventStart": 0,
        "domLoading": 1684471691295,
        "domComplete": 1684471692987,
        "domainLookupStart": 1684471690986,
        "loadEventStart": 1684471692989,
        "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 1684471692121,
        "loadEventEnd": 1684471692995,
        "redirectEnd": 0,
        "connectEnd": 1684471690986
    },
    "navigation": {
        "type": 0,
        "redirectCount": 0
    }
}
```

I would like to understand the meaning of each parameter inside the timing object. Is there any documentation or resource available that explains the significance of these parameters?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Puppeteer, it's just a property that exists on the browser window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of window.performance javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808486/explanation-of-window-performance-javascript)